# Passport-local 304 redirect error express app

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am being throw a redirect error and I can't seem to work out why, I've gone through the docs with a fine-toothed comb and nothing seems wrong. On submitting my forms (both login and register) I receive a 304.

login

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
    user: req.user
  })
})
```

Template

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    h1 Login 
    br
    form(method="post", action="/login", class="form")
      .form-group
        input.form-control(type='text', name='email', required='required')
      .form-group
        input.form-control(type='password', name='password', required='required')
      button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') submit
      a(href='/')
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button') Go back
```

Passport config

```
// Configure passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    UserSchema.authenticate()
  }
));

//passport.use(new LocalStrategy(UserSchema.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(UserSchema.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(UserSchema.deserializeUser())
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your callback function in the `passport.use()` function needs to return in a fashion as below (this is taken from a working implementation from one of my projects).  You can see that the `done()` callback passed into the function is called like `done(null, false)` when authentication was unsuccessful, and `done(null, user)` when authentication is successful (I am passing the user variable here for usage elsewhere).

```
function(username, password, done) {
  //check if user is authenticated, in my case the user variable
  if (err) { return done(err); }
  if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
  if (!user.authenticate(password)) { return done(null, false); }
  if (!user.active) { return done(null, false); }
  return done(null, user);
}
```